# iOs Add My Current Screen to email

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am working on a drawing app , where i have to send the current drawing through email. I managed to get the screen shot of the current screen . But how can i send that image through `MFMailComposeViewControll` email ? here is the code i have used to get the screen shot

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *currentScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:AppName];

NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"amit@gmail.com"]; 
[controller setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *currentScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(currentScreen);
[controller addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"aaa.png"];


[controller setMessageBody:@"body" isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

[controller release];
```

Answer (score 4):

`MFMailComposeViewController` has a `-addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` method. You can use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to convert the image to `NSData`, set `image/png` for the `mimeType`, and set anything you like for `fileName`. And then you can present the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

[image: Document reference]